# Expression.SwitchCase matching issue

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

This is an example copied from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd630254(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
ConstantExpression switchValue = Expression.Constant(3);

// This expression represents a switch statement 
// that has a default case.
SwitchExpression switchExpr =
    Expression.Switch(
        switchValue,
        Expression.Call(
                    null,
                    typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] { typeof(String) }),
                    Expression.Constant("Default")
                ),
        new SwitchCase[] {
            Expression.SwitchCase(
                Expression.Call(
                    null,
                    typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] { typeof(String) }),
                    Expression.Constant("First")
                ),
                Expression.Constant(1)
            ),
            Expression.SwitchCase(
                Expression.Call(
                    null,
                    typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] { typeof(String) }),
                    Expression.Constant("Second")
                ),
                Expression.Constant(2)
            )
        }
    );

// The following statement first creates an expression tree,
// then compiles it, and then runs it.
Expression.Lambda<Action>(switchExpr).Compile()();
//Default
```

It works fine, printing a "Default" to console.

My question is how to make an expression that falls into the next case ("First"). here is what I tried:

```
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));
Expression.Lambda<Action<int>>(switchExpr,pe).Compile()(1);
//
ParameterExpression peo = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
object o = 1;
Expression.Lambda<Action<object>>(switchExpr, peo).Compile()(o);
```

None of them print "First" to console. what's wrong? thx.

**UPDATE:**

I think the MSDN's code is not a perfect example, why switch on a constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example present on this page you can see how to get the "Second" value printed:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.switchcase(v=vs.110).aspx

Your example is not using the value at all but using the fixed 3 at the beginning of the example:

```
ConstantExpression switchValue = Expression.Constant(3);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You are right. my bad. anyway to pass in value at run time?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Ignacio for figuring out the issue.

Here is the code I came up with. 
[image]

full code

```
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));

SwitchExpression switchExpr =
    Expression.Switch(
        pe,
        Expression.Call(
                    null,
                    typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] { typeof(String) }),
                    Expression.Constant("Default")
                ),
        new SwitchCase[] {
            Expression.SwitchCase(
                Expression.Call(
                    null,
                    typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] { typeof(String) }),
                    Expression.Constant("First")
                ),
                Expression.Constant(1)
            ),
            Expression.SwitchCase(
                Expression.Call(
                    null,
                    typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] { typeof(String) }),
                    Expression.Constant("Second")
                ),
                Expression.Constant(2)
            )
        }
    );

var action = Expression.Lambda<Action<int>>(switchExpr,pe).Compile();
action(1);
action(2);
action(3);
```